# In Moose, how can I tell whether one object's class is a subclass of another object's class?

Tags: perl, inheritance, introspection, moose

Suppose I have two objects `$obj1` and `$obj2` that are both instances of Moose classes. I want to find out which of the following applies:

- `$obj1`'s class is the same as `$obj2`'s;
- `$obj1`'s class is a subclass of `$obj2`'s;
- `$obj1`'s class is a superclass of `$obj2`'s;
- Neither object's class is a subclass of the other's.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Is `$obj1`'s class the same as `$obj2`'s?

   ```
   ref $obj1 eq ref $obj2;
   ```
2. Is `$obj1`'s class a subclass of `$obj2`'s?

   ```
   $obj1->isa(ref $obj2);
   ```
3. Is `$obj1`'s class a superclass of `$obj2`'s?

   ```
   $obj2->isa(ref $obj1);
   ```
4. Neither object's class is a subclass of the other's.

   See above.

#### Update:

In response to comments regarding roles applied at run time:

```
package My::X;

use Moose; use namespace::autoclean;

sub boo { }

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package My::Y;

use Moose; use namespace::autoclean;

extends 'My::X';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package My::Z;

use Moose::Role; use namespace::autoclean;

requires 'boo';

package main;

use Test::More tests => 2;

use Moose::Util qw( apply_all_roles );

my $x = My::X->new;
my $y = My::Y->new;

ok($y->isa(ref $x), 'Before role was applied at runtime');

apply_all_roles($x, 'My::Z');

ok($y->isa(ref $x), 'After role was applied at runtime');
```

Output:

```
1..2
ok 1 - Before role was applied at runtime
not ok 2 - After role was applied at runtime
#   Failed test 'After role was applied at runtime' at C:\Temp\t.pl line 36.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

Comment: In Moose, can you add roles or traits to individual objects? It's one of the areas where this thinking goes wrong if you're looking for equivalent behavior.

Comment: Actually, I'm planning to use this logic to make $obj1 and $obj2 mergeable, even in certain cases where one is a subclass of the other. So I need to decide which class's merge code to use. (That is, if I call `$obj1->merge_with($obj2)`, the call will be reversed to `$obj2->merge_with($obj1)` if necessary.)

Comment: @brian you can, but it doesn't cause these snippets to give wrong answers, at least in a pure Liskov substitutability sense (example: if Subclass inherits from Base, $a is an instance of Base+Role (applied to $a at runtime), and $b is an instance of Subclass, it will say $b's class isn't a subclass of $a's class -- but in a very useful sense that's true.)

Comment: @hobbs: are you sure? I think the `->isa` test will pass, even if the base class has roles that the subclass does not (which would violate Liskov).

Answer (score 5):

Using the [`Class::MOP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-MOP/) underpinnings in [`Moose`](http://moose.perl.org) you can introspect all this information.

For eg:

```
{
    package Daddy;
    use Moose;
}

{
    package Kid;
    use Moose;
    extends 'Daddy';
}

my $son      = Kid->new;
my $daughter = Kid->new;

my $sons_class                  = ($son->meta->class_precedence_list)[0];
my $daughters_class             = ($daughter->meta->class_precedence_list)[0];

my @sons_subclasses             = $son->meta->subclasses;     # or better...
my @daughters_subclasses        = $daughter->meta->direct_subclasses;

my @sons_superclasses           = $son->meta->superclasses;

my @Daddies_children            = Daddy->meta->direct_subclasses;
```

Also see this SO question/answer [How can I find all the packages that inherit from a package in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025261/how-can-i-find-all-the-packages-that-inherit-from-a-package-in-perl/2026881#2026881)

/I3az/

Comment: If your using Moose, asking Moose for the answer is probably the right way to go. :)